# PUT is behaving like PATCH | {overwrite: true} is showing weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

[image]

I am making a put request and its being succesfully verified from the console.
Note, that `overwrite` is set to `true` and this is a PUT request.

But, the results I am getting are like :

[image]

Now, if I simply remove the `{overwrite: true}` from my code, the update is successful.:

[image]

Another issue is that, if I make a put request and only provide (for example,) the content, then the title for that doc should just disappear, because thats what PUT does, resplaces the complete doc with the new one.
But, this isn't working. If i dont pass the title and pass only the content, the title remains inact and the content gets updated.
Isn't it the behaviour of PATCH

Answer (score 1):

I have also got the same issue. The solution to this is replace your Collection.updateOne with Collection.findOneAndUpdate in your .put()